# specifying which sequences converge equivalent to specifying topology

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, cauchy-sequences

I know in many cases, specifying which sequences converge is sufficient for specifying which topology is being used. I was wondering in which kinds of scenarios is this necessarily the case, and when it might fail

Comment: The spaces in which sequences determine the topology are precisely the [sequential spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space). The two papers by Stan Franklin listed as references at that link laid the foundation for their study and are freely available as PDFs.

Answer (score 6):

Committing blatant plagiarism I hereby quote [Pete L. Clark](https://mathoverflow.net/users/1149/pete-l-clark)'s answer to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/36379/is-a-topology-determined-by-its-convergent-sequences) question.

> In a metric (or metrizable) space, the topology is entirely determined
> by convergence of sequences. This does not hold in an arbitrary
> topological space, and Mariano has given the canonical counterexample.
> This is the beginning of more penetrating theories of convergence
> given by nets and/or filters. For information on this, see e.g.
>
> [http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/convergence.pdf](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/convergence.pdf)
>
> In particular, Section 2 is devoted to the topic of sequences in
> topological spaces and gives some information on when sequences are
> "topologically sufficient".
>
> In particular a topology is determined by specifying which nets
> converge to which points. This came up as a previous MO question. It
> is not covered in the notes above, but is well treated in Kelley's
> General Topology.

If you go [there](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/36379/is-a-topology-determined-by-its-convergent-sequences), you can find a few examples too.